# Can't edit an array value in closure

Tags: php, closures

Hey, I'm not quite sure if it is a bug or just a feature change:

```
$a = array(array(0));

array_walk(
    $a,
    function (&$e) {
        array_filter(array(), function() use ($e) {});
        $e[] = 1;
    }
);

print_r($a[0]);
```

in PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3 returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

and in PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze19

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

Comment: [_Can't able to reproduce on PHP 5.3_](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Whh1XN) Maybe problem with squeeze ?

Comment: Similar to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54358 perhaps? Fixed in 5.3.7

Comment: @MarkBaker I'd accept that answere if posted accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with the same variable being used repeatedly in closures, sometimes by reference, sometimes by value was a known [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53958) in versions of PHP up to 5.3.5. PHP 5.3.6 attempted to fix the issue, but introduced a new [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54358) in doing so. The problem was finally resolved in PHP 5.3.7